# jq - add entry calculated with external command

Tags: curl, jq, xargs

My input:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "Name": "name 1",
      "Url": "https://some-content.com"
    },
    {
      "Name": "name 2",
      "Url": "https://soming-else.com"
    }
}
```

I want to check `content-type` of each `Url` with `curl` and add it to each object. So, I'll get:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "Name": "name 1",
      "Url": "https://some-content.com",
      "ContentType": "video"
    },
    {
      "Name": "name 2",
      "Url": "https://soming-else.com",
      "ContentType": "text"
    }
}
```

The command I am using to check the value of a `content-type` response header:

```sh
curl -sSL <url> -o /dev/null -w '%{content_type}'
```

I have a feeling that `xargs` is the right way to go, but I haven't figured out how to add the result of it to the input JSON in the fashion described above.

I'm also aware of jq's `=|` operator, but I don't know how to get the result of `xrags` in it.

Is there a solution to my problem? Can it be done with the tools I'm trying to do it with?

Answer (score 1):

You're right about the relevance of `|=` for updating the input, which I'll assume is in a file named input.json

Unfortunately, as you've already noticed, jq doesn't support "external" evaluations, but here is one approach that at least is direct and only requires two invocations of jq:

```
while read url ; do
    curl -sSL "$url" -o /dev/null -w '%{content_type}'
done < <(jq -r .data[].Url input.json) | 
jq -Rn --argfile json input.json '
  [inputs] as $in
  | $json
  | .data |= reduce range(0;length) as $i (.;
               .[$i].ContentType = $in[$i])
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating an array of content types and merging it back into the original JSON:

```
jq '.data[].Url' input.json |\
xargs -n1 curl -sSL -o /dev/null -w '%{content_type}\n' |\
jq --slurp --raw-input 'split("\n")[:-1] | map({"Content-Type": .})' |\
jq -n --argfile in1 input.json --argfile in2 /dev/stdin '$in1 | .data |= ([., $in2] | transpose| map(add))'
```